# SlickGrid excel type functionality - simple

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

Using the SlickGrid editing example to divide duration1 / duration2.  Can this be done on keyup change for each row on change?

```
$(function()
    {


        for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
            var d = (data[i] = {});

            d["title"] = "Task " + i;
            d["duration1"] = "";
            d["duration2"] = "";
            d["percentComplete"] = (d["duration1"] / d["duration2"]);
            d["start"] = "01/01/2009";
            d["finish"] = "01/05/2009";
            d["effortDriven"] = (i % 5 == 0);
        }

        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

        //grid.registerPlugin(new Slick.CellRangeSelector());

        grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());

        grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function(e, args) {
            var item = args.item;
            var column = args.column;
            grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
            data.push(item);
            grid.updateRowCount();
            grid.render();
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e, args) {
  args.item["percentComplete"] = args.item["duration1"] / args.item["duration2"];
  this.updateRow(args.row);
});
```

Comment: The more I play with SlickGrid, the more I love it's power.  Thanks, worked perfectly!

Comment: Just remember, with great power comes great responsibility :)